# drand48() always returns same value

Tags: function, random, swift3, xcode8

### drand48() always returns the same value after I close the app and open it again

When I call drand48() and print out the result it's always the same after closing and opening the app.

Does anybody know how to prevent that from happening and get a random number each time without a predictable pattern?

Thank you very much

Comment: Use `arc4random_uniform` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem unexpected. Quoting from [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/drand48.html) (emphasis mine):

> The `srand48()`, `seed48()` and `lcong48()` are initialisation entry points, one of which should be invoked before either `drand48()`, `lrand48()` or `mrand48()` is called. (Although it is not recommended practice, **constant default initialiser values will be supplied automatically** if `drand48()`, `lrand48()` or `mrand48()` is called **without a prior call to an initialisation entry point**.)

So if you don't seed the PRNG prior to using it, you'll get a constant seed, which means you'll get exactly the same sequence every time.

Note that you should usually seed exactly once, in your case probably at startup, and never in a loop where you also use the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

drand48 creates a Pseudo-random number sequence. You need to set a different seed every run.

Something like this

```
let time = UInt32(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate) srand48(Int(time)) let number = drand48 ()
```